# How to save a list with Boolean values in SharedPreferences in kotlin?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, save, sharedpreferences

I want to save this list in SharedPreferences with Boolean values:

`val listTheme = mutableListOf( false,false,true,false)`

how can this be done? in kotlin language in android studio

Comment: Either store them under numbered keys (e.g., `theme_1`, `theme_2`, etc.) or convert them into a string representation (e.g., JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Kotlin Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md) library to store data structures (including classes and lists) as JSON strings - there are other libraries too. But for something simple like this, you can probably get away with doing it yourself:

```
val listTheme = mutableListOf(false, false, true, false)

// convert each value to a specific character (produces a string)
val serialized = listTheme.map { if (it) '1' else '0' }.joinToString("")

// convert each character to a true or false value (produces a list)
val deserialized = serialized.map { it == '1' }

print(" original: $listTheme\n serialized: $serialized\n deserialized: $deserialized")

>>>  original: [false, false, true, false]
 serialized: 0010
 deserialized: [false, false, true, false]
```

Then you can just throw it in a String preference, and convert it back to a list when you fetch it later.